# Efficiently Searching an Entire API in Flutter with Limited Server-side Support

Tags: flutter, performance, search, pagination

I'm currently working on a Flutter application where I need to search the entire API. However, the API doesn't offer server-side search capabilities, which presents a challenge in terms of efficiency. Here are the key details of the problem:

- The API I'm working with lacks server-side search functionality.
- The dataset within the API is extensive, making it impractical to fetch all data at once.
- I want to ensure a responsive user experience when performing searches.
- My goal is to find the most efficient approach to search through the API's dataset.

In my efforts to address the aforementioned problem, I've explored several options. Here's a summary of what I've tried and the expectations I had:

I attempted to use incremental offset pagination, sending multiple GET requests with different offsets to the API. However, this approach is time-consuming and not feasible due to the large dataset.